# Preventing MATLAB from rounding numbers and set decimal precision

Tags: matlab, casting, rounding, number-formatting

I'm trying to display values received from serial but Matlab doesn't accept decimal numbers results.
I would like to receive A=0.123 from a device, the values is multiplied by 1000 and then sent via serial to matlab.

The matlab script receives 123 but when that number is divided in order to get the original value, matlab shows 0.

```
consRollKpTemp = typecast([uint8(mess(typei + 1)), uint8(mess(typei + 2)),uint8(mess(typei + 3)), uint8(mess(typei + 4))], 'int32');
disp(consRollKpTemp);
consRollKp = consRollKpTemp/1000;
disp(consRollKp);
```

Which returns

```
consRollKpTemp:
         123    
consRollKp:
           0
```

I thought the problem was the [typecast(X,type)](http://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/typecast.html) function which

> converts a numeric value in X to the data type specified by type.

and I changed it to:

```
consRollKpTemp = typecast([uint8(mess(typei + 1)), uint8(mess(typei + 2)),uint8(mess(typei + 3)), uint8(mess(typei + 4))], 'single');
```

But nothing changed. I've tried the suggestions in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23492523/how-to-prevent-a-decimal-number-being-rounded-to-a-whole-number) question and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7862476/prevent-matlab-from-rounding-output) but they didnt' work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `int32` as type, i.e. you only have integer numbers and 0.23 is correctly rounded to 0. Try to cast the variable `consRollKp` to `double` before dividing it by 1000:

```
consRollKp = double(consRollKpTemp) / 1000;
```

To clarify: Using `typecast` with `single` will not work. Typecast converts data types *without* changing the underlying data. As `single` is a floating point number and `uint8` and `int32` are integer types, a `typecast` between those will not lead to the desired results.

Try to `typecast` to `int32` (or probably `uint32`) and in a second step use `dobule()` or `single()` to convert this variable to a floating point type. Finally you should be able to divide by 1000 and get the correct result.